# C# - How can I get the first item of a custom collection without using an indexer?

Tags: c#, arrays, class, collections

So, I am trying to build a custom typed collection where it could access the first item in the collection if I did not use an indexer.
Assuming the class starts something like this..

```
public class myCollection : IEnumerable<myCustomObject>
{
...
```

I'd want to use it like so:

```
var coll = new myCollection();    
coll.someMember = "test";
coll[3].someMember = "test3";
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Edit: There seems to be a way to use the keyword 'this' as part of the constructor but I don't know how to actually do so and if it would satisfy what I need it for.

Comment: Why does your class `has-a` collection and also `is-a` collection?

Comment: `IEnumerable<T>` allows you to enumerate but not edit or perform random access, `ICollection<T>` builds on top of `IEnumerable<T>` and adds the ability to add, remove and count items. `IList<T>` extends `ICollection<T>` to add an indexer. Maybe you just want to implement `IList<T>` instead? Alternatively, you could stay with `IEnumerable<T>` but add an indexer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ilist-1.item?view=netcore-3.1#System_Collections_Generic_IList_1_Item_System_Int32_

Comment: I... I think that's how I initially learned how to make custom collections. Now that I think about it, doesn't make any sense. Thanks, I'll remove that.

Comment: @MartinCostello , Thanks, I will look into both IList<T> and the indexer.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand the logic behind the class structure descending from a collection and also having a collection, but I guess I don't need to:

```
var coll = new myCollection();    //for this to work your myCollection class needs an accessible constructor
coll.someMember = "test";         //for this to work your myCollection class needs a property called someMember
coll[3].someMember = "test3";     //for this to work your myCollection class needs an indexer that uses the parent collection's ElementAt and myCustomObject class needs a property called someMember
```

By "your myCollection class needs an indexer" I mean you need something like this property:

```
public myCustomObject this[int idx]{
  get { return base.ElementAt(idx); }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Wasn't sure about the indexer property.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a strange request, and you should probably consider whether you are making your code a bit confusing for future developers, but you can accomplish it by having your collection implement the same interface as your collection type:

```
    public interface IMyCustomObject
    {
        string SomeMember { get; }
    }

    public class MyCustomObject : IMyCustomObject
    {
        public string SomeMember => "Hi";
    }

    public class MyCollection : IEnumerable<MyCustomObject>, IMyCustomObject
    {            
        public string SomeMember => this.FirstOrDefault()?.SomeMember;
    }
```